# ASP.Net Core - When you close the C# project, the session information is also deleted

Tags: c#, session

I keep the login information in the session when the project is opened, but when I run the project again, the session information is reset. Could you please help on this issue?

```
services.AddHttpClient("CoreSession", c =>
             {
                 c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44331/api");
             });
```

```
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Id", parameter.Id);
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("CompanyId", parameter.CompanyId);
```

I tried everything I could find, but each time the project restarted, the session information was reset.

Comment: Where is the session data stored? In memory?

Comment: Session data is supposed to be ephemeral. What problem are you trying to solve? If you're expecting your session to be restored through a cookie from the client, then you will need to use a longer-lasting session store, like a database.